# Django filters: custom filter methods with different lookup expressions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filters

I'm using [Django filters](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/) along with Django Rest Framework to create filters for API views.
They have a nice syntax that I show in the `age` field filter below defined in the class meta
`fields = {'age': ['exact', 'gte', 'lte', 'lt', 'gt', 'in']}` which allows the creation of all these greater than or equal to, less than or equal to, less than, greater than etc filters for the field all at once...

With a custom field like the `artworks_count` I also show below, however, it seems I need to add different methods for each lookup expression, which is quite repetitive. I'm just wondering if there isn't a better way to do this? (perhaps using something other than the `NumberFilter`?) that would take a `lookup_expression` as an argument and allow me to construct a single method using it

```
class UserFilter(django_rest_filters.FilterSet):


    artworks_count__gte = django_rest_filters.NumberFilter(method="filter_artworks_count__gte")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {'age': ['exact', 'gte', 'lte', 'lt', 'gt', 'in']}

    def filter_artwork_count__gte(self, qs, name, value):
        return qs.annotate(art_count=Count('artworks')).filter(art_count__gte=value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own base filter from which you can inherit and define your model field filters.

```py
from django_filters import (
    BaseInFilter,
    BaseRangeFilter,
    BooleanFilter,
    FilterSet,
    NumberFilter,
)


### first, create filterset class attributes

def create_custom_method_filters(filter_name, base_filter_class, lookups, func):
    custom_method_name = f'filter_{filter_name}'

    def custom_method(self, queryset, name, value):
        return func(queryset, name, value)
    boolean_lookups = ('isnull', 'isempty')
    in_lookups = ('in',)
    range_lookups = ('range',)
    d = dict(
        **{
            f'{filter_name}__{lookup}' if lookup != 'exact' else filter_name: base_filter_class(method=custom_method_name)
            for lookup in lookups
            if lookup not in boolean_lookups + in_lookups + range_lookups
        },
        **{
            f'{filter_name}__{lookup}': BooleanFilter(method=custom_method_name)
            for lookup in lookups
            if lookup in boolean_lookups
        },
        **{
            f'{filter_name}__{lookup}': type('InFilter', (BaseInFilter, base_filter_class), {})(method=custom_method_name)
            for lookup in lookups
            if lookup in in_lookups
        },
        **{
            f'{filter_name}__{lookup}': type('RangeFilter', (BaseRangeFilter, base_filter_class), {})(method=custom_method_name)
            for lookup in lookups
            if lookup in range_lookups
        },
        **{
            custom_method_name: custom_method,
        },
    )
    return d

### second, create your base filter for the specific filter

UserFilterBase = type(
    'UserFilterBase',
    (FilterSet,),
    create_custom_method_filters(
        'artworks_count',
        NumberFilter,
        ['exact', 'in', 'gt', 'gt', 'lt', 'lte', 'range'],
        lambda queryset, name, value: queryset.annotate(artworks_count=Count('artworks')).filter(**{name: value}),
    ),
)

### Then, inherit from that base class and use the filter meta as usual.


class UserFilter(UserFilterBase):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {'age': ['exact', 'gte', 'lte', 'lt', 'gt', 'in']}
```

In Python 3.9+, you can replace the ugly `dict(**{…}, **{…})` construction with a much nicer `{…} | {…}` construction